# Camel netty consumer always sends immediate response even if route not finished

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am using apache camel 3.8 and trying to make a simple tcp server that sends the request message back to the client (the client I am using is PacketSender).
The problem is, if the `process()` method takes too long an empty response is sent back by netty in the background after 15ms, even if the `process()` is still in the `Thread.sleep` hold.
If I do not let the method (thread) sleep, the response is sent with the received content immediatly.

How can I manage it, that netty is waiting until I finished my process and send the response I set in the exchange message body?

Here is the route I am using:

```java
fromF("netty:tcp://%s:%d?sync=true&synchronous=true&disconnectOnNoReply=false&connectTimeout=100000", host, receivePort)
    .bean(HL7Request.class, "process", BeanScope.Request);
```

The bean process method looks like this, for simulation purpose of my long taking process I used a Thread.sleep:

```java
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        try {
            CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
            exchange.setException(null);

            Thread.sleep(5000); // <-- Here the method stopps for 5 seconds but the response is sent by netty anyway
            String content = exchange.getMessage().getBody(String.class);
            System.out.println(content);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            exchange.setException(e);
        }
    }
```

[PacketSender receives an empty response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M9HN.png)

Thank you.
Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

I think it was an issue with PacketSender Software. It perfectly works using command line telnet.

[More details to the bug](https://github.com/dannagle/PacketSender/issues/173)